# How can I animate this material like this?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, uv, shaders

In Blender, I have two materials; one of them is for the face, and the other is for the lipstick.

These are the nodes of the material of the lipstick:
[image]

These are the nodes of the material of the face:
[image]

So I want to animate the lipstick like this that the face including lips at the first frame has only `Material.001` and then the material of the lips are changing to that red material that looks like a lipstick. I don't want the face material to just change its opacity to that red material I want it to appear like this:

[image]

The above gif is something that I made in a 2D software to make it clear what I mean.

I tried the answer but it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want that "one full face turns red after the previous one" kind of effect, or is it ok if it kind of sweeps over time covering all the faces?

Comment: This is what Imean by sweeping : https://i.imgur.com/F5Fr3Yn.gif

Comment: @TheKalaakaar What you did is acceptable; you can answer if you want. But did you do it in a different way than in the below answer?

Comment: I did it in almost the same way. Only difference that I seperated the UV map's x and y coordinate and used a greater than node. The UV square stuff was the same. Well, it doesn't matter now. Hope his answer helped.Have a nice day

Comment: @TheKalaakaar There is a problem; I did the same as the answer below, but it just changed the color, not the material itself. In the gif you showed it works the way I wanted, what am I doing wrong? I updated my post.

Comment: There is a small thing which probably both of you missed. I will write an answer and clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did:

Just like in the answer provided by moonboots I made the UVs and straightened them out with the UV Squares addon. Now I laid that island in a way that it covers the Y-axis of the UV space from 0-1. Like this:
[image]

Next, in the shader, I seperated the Y-axis of the UV map and used a Less Than Math Node to get a mask. Now I simply used this mask as the factor for a mix shader node. In moonboots's answer, he plugged the colour output from his colorramp into the base color of the principled bsdf. But this meant that there is only one single shader. This was probably the problem you are having. Anyways this is the node setup:
[image]

And the final output:

[image]

Note: A few other things which might mess tihngs up:

1. I noticed that you were using a texture for the first material. If you really need it, then create a second UV map and use it for all the UV square hulabaloo
2. In the mix shader, the red one is your metallic lipstick thingy material and the skin coloured one is the exact same material as the one in the first slot.(Atleast that is what is shown in the gif provided by you) Make sure all the values match, or else it will look different.
   In case you do want it to look different, you can. Obviously no issues with that.

Comment: This was the way I did it. I guess you wouldn't strictly need  a second UV map, if important for economy.. you could, say, map the lips lined up  along the bottom of UV space, mask out 'Y<whatever' in another mix to reserve that region for the lips, and  animate their threshold in X, without affecting the rest of the texture.

Answer (score 1):

Select the lips and give them another material with a *ColorRamp* that has both the skin color and the lips color, create a seam where it is supposed to cut, unwrap, enable the *UV Squares* addon and in the *UV Editor> N panel > UV Squares*, click on the *To Grid By Shape* button:

[image]

Now when you move the *Location* value of the *Mapping* node you can make the lips color progress:

[image]

Comment: the master strikes back again... +1